# Clear Formatting button in TinyMce

Tags: tinymce

I want add  **Clear Formatting** button to TinyMce toolbar. How to add **Clear Formatting** button to tinyMce toolbar.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Use **removeformat** button like following:

```
tinymce.init({
    ...
    toolbar: "...| removeformat | ...",
    ...       
});
```

[List of all TinyMce V3 buttons](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs-3x/reference/buttons/)